# How to display a horizontal line before and after a heading in css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to style a an html heading in css but am not getting the correct result as my jsfiddle shows: https://jsfiddle.net/Nadjanara/nmo0245t/ .
The following are the html and css codes:

```
<h2><span>Heading2</span></h2>

h2{
  width:100%; 
  text-align:center; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
  line-height:0.1em; margin:10px 0 20px; 
} 
h2 span{
  padding:0 10px; 
}
```

How can I put the horizontal line only before and after the heading and also control the width of the line so that such doesn't occupy the full width of the screen?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There's obviously many ways you can achieve what you're after. But how about something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xfqz478g/)?

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
}
h1::before,
h1::after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    border-top: .3rem solid black;
    width: 4rem;
    margin: 0 1rem;
    transform: translateY(-1rem);
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

Comment: Indeed. It looks better than it was. But two problems still remain: the lines are a bit too closed to the heading. And that the line is bit thrown to the top and not displayed in the middle: like p ----

Comment: So make the adjustments to the transform percentage and margin. All you need to do is get the right relative proportions and you're done - no more adjustments necessary.

Comment: @Nadj. Like Jonathan said. Just add a margin-left and right to it. change transform to 90% and with to em. check the jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/fkrc15mh/

Answer (score 4):

Give this a shot! A pseduo-element will be your best bet here. You can change the width of the line to whatever you need it, but for this example I used 500px.

```
h2{ 
  text-align:center;
  line-height:0.1em;
  position:relative;
  margin:10px 0 20px; 
  background:#FFF;
} 
h2 span{
   background:#FFF;
   z-index:2;
   position: relative;
}
h2:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  top:50%;
  height:1px;
  width: 500px;
  background:#000;
  left:50%;
  z-index:1;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: It got better now that I can control the full width of the line. But still the problem remains because I am not being able to give space between the heading and the line( on the left and right side).
Example:  ------  heading  -----. 
Instead of ----------heading------------

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked very well

```css
.divider-text {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.divider-text:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.divider-text span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider-text"><span>Additional text</span></div>
```